# The iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s simulators disappeared after upgrading to Xcode 8. How do I get them back?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have these iPhone simulators:

- iPhone 5
- iPhone 5s
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6 Plus
- iPhone 6s
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone SE

What happened to the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**1)** You have to **download** at least **iOS 8.x, 9.x SDKs** to be able to run iPhone 4S simulator.

[image]

**2)** Your **deployment target should remain at least 9.x** to see iPhone 4S simulator in the list of offered simulators in your project.

[image]

I have an Xcode 8 and these simulators available:

[image]

Comment: What is the menu option to get to these SDKs?  And why do you not have the iPhone 7 as a simulator?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 8 includes simulator from iPhone 5 & higher with default deployment target 10.0, but you can add a new simulator.

1.) Change "iOS Deployment target 10.0" to 9.3

2.) In "iOS Simulators" Choose Download simulators

3.) Simulator downloading like this:

[image]

Select the simulator that you will need.

4.) Wait for it to be downloaded.

5.) Add new simulator.

6.) Enjoy =D

Answer (score 3):

iOS10 will not support iPhone 4 or iPhone 4s. Hence it's removed by apple from Xcode8.

If you still want to use 7.1 ( copy the disk image from Xcode 7 ). This will work but not sure if it's allowed to do so .

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1

Comment: This would not add old deployment targets.

Comment: @Sergei i have tried this and it works. Can you please elobrate would not add old targets? When you copy above disk image you will need to reopen new Xcode and choose your device, you might get an error message, click on fix issue and you should able to use it.

Comment: I was searching for 7.0 in the dropdown list. But then I typed it by hands and this works.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a quick solution - use an iPad simulator. It mimics screen size of iPhone 4.
If you have a universal app - disable this feature temporary (open your target -> select 'General' tab -> scroll down to 'Deployment Info' section -> click on 'Devices' dropdown -> select 'iPhone').

Comment: You saved my day.. I was about to download iOS 9.x sdk & iPhone 4S simulator. One thing I would like to tell you is that you have to use iPad Pro -> 9.7 Inch simulator as it mimics screen size of iPhone 4 / 4S. iPad Pro -> 12.9 Inch mimics screen size of iPhone 5 / 5C / 5S / SE. I haven't tried with iPad Air simulators.

Comment: @YahyaIbrahim - not any more it seems - huhuhu -I get a 5S proportioned display with black vertical bars either side if I display it at 2x..   Makes a mockery of including it in the View As.. list at the bottom of Interface Builder