# iPhone 4 simulator with XCode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to use my iPhone 4 with Xcode 8, and am running into this error:

> Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 4 is running iOS
>   7.1.2 (11D257), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

There are a number of existing StackOverflow questions related to this issue (see links below).  The general accepted answer is to:

> Copy DeviceSupport folder for iOS 7.1 from Xcode 7 to the new one. It's located in: 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1

I'm having trouble actually following this advice.  I've located the /DeviceSupport/ folder in Xcode, which has a number of folders inside it for versions 8.0 - 10.2.  Should I create a new folder in it called `7.1/`, and copy the contents of `10.2/` into the folder?  Should I install an older version of Xcode (version 7), and copy the folder in that version of Xcode into the newer one?  Thanks for your help.

**Related questions:**

[Any way to install app to iPhone 4 with Xcode 8 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306688/any-way-to-install-app-to-iphone-4-with-xcode-8-beta)

[The iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s simulators disappeared after upgrading to Xcode 8. How do I get them back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549111/the-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s-simulators-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-xcode-8-ho)

Comment: You need to install an Xcode version that supports iOS 7.1 development, and copy from there.

Comment: As for simulators, you will have no luck. And if you have upgraded your OS, you will also not be able to run the older simulator frameworks.