# Guideline 2.4.1 Releasing to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am trying to submit an app to the app store, and this is the issue I got:

> Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility We noticed that
>   your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad.

I have set constraints on all the view controllers. Would you know how to solve this issue (I have seen other posts related to this, but none have had an answer on how to solve that problem? Also, this has nothing to do with the deployment target, because I released only for iPhone, it is just that apple wants it to work for both iPhone and iPad, for some reason)?

Comment: "because I released only for iPhone"  What does your Info.plist say?

Comment: what do I check in info.plist?

Comment: Sorry...  I guess info.plist doesn't say about the device.  Is Devices under Deployment Info set to iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

**Possible Solution (that worked for us)**

View the app in iPhone 4 and design for that as well. For some reason the view dimensions of iPhone 4 and iPad are the same.

**Thoughts**

I had this issue happen to me a couple months ago. It basically means your app is not usable when used on iPads. This definition of un-usable could mean buttons are blocked off items are not structured correctly.

Comment: Maybe he means iPhone 4s?

Comment: No because there is no simulator for 4s either, for some reason?

Comment: Checkout this to get iPhone 4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549111/the-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s-simulators-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-xcode-8-ho